Which philosopher, if any, has defined matter as persistence of experience?
I vaguely remember reading somewhere on the internet that, according to one thinker, materiality can be defined as a property of perceived persistence/stability. I.e. your hand by this definition is material, because even if you close your eyes and open them again, you'll still see your hand, as before, with all the same features.
While searching for the answer, I had stumbled upon such philosophers as George Berkeley, Edmund Husserl and Ernst Mach, however neither of them seems to be the author of the definition above.
Maybe someone here knows the actual source, if it even exists?

Nisargadatta Maharaj defined matter as the point where consciousness stops — I can feel the wall; I cannot feel its inside, being inside.  Mach famously defined physics as the study of sensations

"Idealists conceive of the world in terms of our actual experiences (and, for Berkeley, those of God). Phenomenalists hold a related position: for them, propositions about the physical world should be seen as propositions about our possible experiences. Or, as Mill (1867) claims, material objects are nothing but “permanent possibilities of sensation”" IEP. The reference is to Mill's Examination of Sir William Hamilton’s Philosophy.

Strictly speaking it's not "matter" or "materiality" that this applies to, but "physical/perceived objects". In cognitive and developmental psychology there are studies about "object permanence" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_permanence). Philosophers planted the idea, but psychologists did the interesting research.

Henri Bergson uses the concept of "duree" (duration, roughly speaking) to describe existence and so too experience. Around the turn of the 1900's Henri Bergson was perhaps the most well-known and famous of philosophers. It's reductive, and as plausible as Schopenhauer's reduction to will, but it does land squarely in the "being is duration" camp.

This sounds like the concept of object permanence in psychology.

Physicists have known the answer for about 100 years - and your guy has the right answer too.
In disk 5 of his Australia lectures (and in his easy pieces book), Nobel winning Richard Feynman explains that the only thing that really exists is energy (momentum in some direction).
This momentum can be in a direction of space, when mass is moved.
Or it can be momentum in the direction of future time. That's what mass is, and that's all that it is. Anything that persists into the future is mass.
Anything that does not perceive the passage of time, like light itself, is not mass; It's the other kind of energy.

I don't know all the implications of E = mc^2, which holds that mass and energy are equivalent, nor how this informs Feynman's description of mass as momentum in the direction of future time. My intuition tells me there may be a circular definition of time that depends on the concepts of mass and energy such as the mass at the bottom of an oscillating pendulum with momentum and resonant energy states. I think the concept of conservation of momentum is fundamental to classical physics and the jumping off point for nuclear physics, quantum mechanics, and relativity. Time is inverse frequency.

@SystemTheory > E = mc^2,  how does this informs Feynman's description of mass as momentum in the direction of future time? = = The speed of light is the conversion factor between space and time, and it's ALSO the conversion factor between mass and energy. That's because momentum in time is mass, and momentum in space is energy.

This article says, https://courses.lumenlearning.com/suny-physics/chapter/28-3-length-contraction/ Close to the speed of light, distances measured are not the same when measured by different observers. The definitions seem to be circular to me. Every observer has an atomic clock to measure both time and length but their clocks change rates at relativistic speeds so different observers all measure the same speed of light, and seem to possess the same standard units of time and length, but the clocks are not synchronized the the lengths differ! Classical mass is a component of momentum p = mv.

@SystemTheory length changes, so what?

Momentum is defined as mass times velocity. Velocity is displacement (length) over time. If length varies so does momentum. I have not taken courses in special or general relativity so maybe I am missing something in those math models. It is not clear to me how momentum can be mass in the direction of time when momentum itself is defined in terms of mass, length, and time; and further length and time depend on relativistic velocity.  The thinking seems to be circular to me. I think there is questionable equivocation when stating that mass is momentum persisting in the direction of time.

@SystemTheory " I have not taken courses in special or general relativity" = = That doesn't matter at all. You're intelligent and curious and well-intentioned. That's not worth anything IRL, but here it's all that matters. "The thinking seems to be circular to me." = = First of all, that's not my crackpot theory. It's Richard Feynman's, and he said it very explicitly in the two places that I referenced. Mass is what it is. If you don't like it, tell it to God; I just work here.

@SystemTheory Look, The equation for 4-momentum has two components: Rest mass is momentum in the direction of time. If the object is also moving through space, then it has also has classical momentum. It's really simple. Einstein and Feynman didn't see things that they thought were complex. Rather, they saw the simplicity in things that everybody else thought were complex.

PS: Length doesn't have anything to do with it. A ruler will always measure itself as being 12 inches in (proper) length, no matter where it is or how fast it's going, if it's being accelerated, or what gravitational field that's in. For the same reason, proper (wristwatch)  time always passes at 1 second per second.

I am going to watch this video Relativistic Energy and Momentum: Exlpained - https://youtu.be/X4xLx8fxdy4 and see if I can decode the meaning of Feynman's statements to my satisfaction.
